# Could not find main method from given launch configuration

Tags: eclipse, jar, executable-jar, manifest.mf

I've a simple Java project that works when I execute it at Eclipse environment. But when I try to export it to a *Runnable Jar*, I get  the following error:

```
JAR export finished with warnings. See details for additional information.
Exported with compile warnings: JavaSwing/src.main.java/com/cansoft/GUIProgram.java
Exported with compile warnings: JavaSwing/src.main.java/com/util/Util.java
Jar export finished with problems. See details for additional information.
  Could not find main method from given launch configuration.
```

I read other posts which suggest to create a MANIFEST.MF file specifying the main-class which I did. It is placed at MyProjectFolder/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF and it contains the following information:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: resources
main-class: com.cansoft.GUIProgram
```

My main class is as follows:

```
public class GUIProgram {
    
    private JFrame folderCreationSubappFrame;
    private Color color;
    private String home;
    
    private final static Logger LOG_MONITOR = Logger.getLogger("com.cansoft");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            new GUIProgram();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG_MONITOR.log(Level.INFO,e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public GUIProgram() throws InterruptedException, SecurityException, IOException {
        home = System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "Documents";
        startLogSystem();
        if(isFirstRun()) {
            showWelcomeFrame();
        } else {
            initialize();
        }
    }  .... More and more code
```

Does anybody know what am I missing? Any help much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find out where the problem was, it was quite simple btw. I had created my GUIProgram within a `src.main.java` package, but that package was created (my bad) as *resources* instead of folders, so Eclipse was smart enought to run it but when trying to generate the JAR which expected a correct java project structure, it was failing because truly there were not GUIProgram java class at `src` path (src was not folder type but resources).

Hope I succeed explaining.

Answer (score 1):

It is not enough to create the manifest file, you need to explicitly choose it in the Eclipse jar export dialog.

### Answer to Comment

If you use "runnable jar", make sure that you chose the correct launch configuration and that the launch configuration successfully runs when chosing "Run As" -> "Run Configurations" -> "Java Application" -> Your Configuration -> "Run"

Comment: Hello Konrad and thank you for your answer, but Manifest selection option only appears when exporting Jar, not runnable JAR (If I export it as JAR, I have two options: let wizard to create Manifest or choose mine from a path).

Comment: Hi Konrad. Yes, If I launch the run configuration, the app starts and operates normally. Please, take a look to the run configuration: https://ibb.co/71G90DD and to the Export dialog: https://ibb.co/k9ZkL3f. Thanks again